# Magento 2 EE elasticsearch Content-Type header is not supported

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, magento2.2, magento-enterprise-2, elasticsearch

I have successfully integrated elastic search(Elasticsearch 6.0) with Magento Enterprise Edition 2.1. As per their documentation, I have tried to reindex calalog by using magento cli command

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

But it throws an error like

```
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
Content-Type header [] is not supported
```

I read that,Elasticsearch 6.0 is implemented [strict content-type](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strict-content-type-checking-for-elasticsearch-rest-requests) checking.So how can I solve this in Magento EE 2.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Magento EE [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/cloud/project/project-conf-files_services-elastic.html), they support Elasticsearch versions 1.4, 1.7, and 2.4. The default version is 1.7.

But I tried to inegrate latest version of elasticsearch (Elasticsearch 6.0).I have installed elasticsearch 2.4 and working fine now.

Comment: yes magento2 ee not working with latest  elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

Problem in the module - `"magento/module-elasticsearch"`. In this module "composer.json" contain `"elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~2.0"`.
And he doesn't support Elasticsearch 6.0.

For version 6, there should be an additional parameter "Content-Type" in header to be sent
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/commit/fd3b0f16f7e09cb2096ef5f2d656c9fd8dd3d61d#diff-1b0215334399d80759820e3229367adf

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/master/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php, line 159, `$this->headers`

```
$request = [
'http_method' => $method,
'scheme'      => $this->transportSchema,
'uri'         => $this->getURI($uri, $params),
'body'        => $body,
'headers'     => array_merge([
'Host'  => [$this->host]
], $this->headers)
];
```